# Run command on powershell launch using pwd variable

Tags: powershell, registry

When you're in file explorer you can click on `File > Open Windows Powershell`(or its icon in the Quick Access Toolbar) to start an instance of Powershell in the directory that your file explorer is in. I would like to then automatically run a simple command in this directory and close the Powershell window after it is done.

I have tried adding my command to my Powershell Profile but it executes before the path variable has been set and it runs with `$pwd` being equal to `C:\Users\MyUsername` (my home directory) or `C:\WINDOWS\system32` (seems to be a race condition of some sort, no idea why it does one or the other). To the best of my understanding this is because the file explorer "open in powershell button" opens powershell and THEN cd's to the directory I was in in file explorer. So when the profile.ps1 is ran it is using the only directories it knows if since the cd call hasn't been made yet. This is similar to running the command `start powershell.exe` in cmd vs `start powershell.exe -command "cd 'C:\wherever'"`. The former correctly runs my profile command while the latter uses the current directory of cmd and not the `C:\wherever`.

So, obviously the `$pwd` variable is being assigned at different times in the case of opening it from cmd and opening it from file explorer. Is there some way to delay the execution of a command in the profile until after the shell has fully loaded? Simply sleeping the script doesn't help.

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to edit the registry so that I can change the behavior of clicking `File > Open Windows Powershell` (since it must have access to some variable storing the current directory and I assume it calls the Powershell executable with this variable as an argument being cd'd to), that would work too.

Then again I could be incredibly naive about how `File > Open Windows Powershell` and the Powershell instantiation process works.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to close the Powershell window when the user is requesting it? Must the solution work for all the users on a device?

Comment: Can you show exactly what code you put in the profile that didn't work?

Comment: As for the alternative: Have a look [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/165268/how-to-add-open-powershell-here-to-the-context-menu-in-windows/)

Comment: Register a command with 'ConEmu here'?

Comment: @Theo I know you can add to or edit the context menu when right clicking but I'd like to add to or edit the File menu or more preferably the Quick Access Toolbar.

Comment: @JeroenHeier The current idea is to work around powershell being the only supported option in file explorer by having powershell launch, execute a command to open another program, and then immediately close

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The command works when invoked after Powershell has started, but when in the Profile it uses the wrong value for `$pwd` (I updated my post to better explain). The command is along the lines of `& C:\Path\To\Program "$pwd"`

Comment: @Maximus As I told Theo, I'd like to add it to the Quick Access toolbar :) There are several reasons using the context menu can be messy

Comment: @JeroenHeier I don't actually use Powershell for anything other than this, and I'm the only user on this device, so I feel comfortable configuring it for this one specific purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a much cleaner and faster way to do this. All I had to do was set up my profile to look like this, no tasks or second instance of powershell required

```
function Prompt
{
    & C:\Program` Files\MyProgram\MyProgram.exe "$pwd"
    stop-process -Id $PID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the most hacky, gross way ever, but without easy access to Windows internals this is the only working method I could find. I set up my powershell profile to make my window title my prompt like so:

```
function Prompt
{
  $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = $(get-location)
  “PS> “
}
```

Then I set up a task in the `Task Scheduler` that was triggered by powershell reaching its prompt (there are 3 possible hooks, when the console is starting up, when it starts an IPC listening thread, and when the console is ready for input). I used the `Event Viewer` to do this (I was going to post screenshots but I don't have 10 reputation yet).

Then, I set the action on this task to run the script shown below, which reads from the window title of my first instance of powershell

```
Start-Sleep -s 1
$A = Get-Process -Name powershell | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Id -ne $PID}
$B = $A.MainWindowTitle
& C:\Program` Files\MyProgram\MyProgram.exe "$B"
stop-process -Id $A.Id
stop-process -Id $PID
```

This whole menagerie of events properly runs my program with the current file explorer directory as an argument (and then closes powershell) when I click the little powershell icon on the quick access toolbar in file explorer.